# jQuery tools tooltip doesn't appear in first try after hide()

Tags: jquery, settimeout, jquery-events, jquery-tools, jquery-ui-tooltip

I've used `tooltip` for a `<div>`.
It will `hide()` after couple of seconds.
If I'll mouse over it's trigger after it.
For the first time it will not appear.
Only after I move the mouse over it the second time it will appear.
I used `onShow` event for binding and used `window.setTimeOut`.

Is it a problem in the tooltip or in jQuery?

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    x = $("button").tooltip({
        api: true,
        position: "center right",
        onShow: function() {
            var hid = function() {
                x.getTip().hide();
            };
            window.setTimeout(hid, 2000);
        }});
    x.show();
    });
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vKa5Z/1/)

Comment: Without code, it's difficult to say. Could just compare your code to that on the official site: http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html

Comment: added demo, thing is I want it to `fadeOut` and not `hide`

Comment: **jQuery Tools** has not been updated in a very long time.  It's likely it's not fully compatible with the latest version of jQuery.  You also may find [this article](http://marcgrabanski.com/articles/jquery-tools-vs-jquery-ui) interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I've fixed it:
answer here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    x = $("button").tooltip({
        api: true,
        **effect:"fade"**,
        position: "center right",
        onShow: function() {
            var hid = function() {
                **x.hide();**
            };
            window.setTimeout(hid, 2000);
        }});
    x.show();
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vKa5Z/5/