# jQuery Tools Tooltips won't fade in after a fade out until the 2nd hover of a link

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

I am having an issue with jQuery Tools Tooltips. The functionality I have at the moment is that when a user hovers over a link the tooltip shows and doesn't exit until the user hits the 'Esc' key or clicks somewhere on the page that isn't the tooltip.

My issue is that once the tooltip fades out but won't fade in the next time you hover the link. Its only after the 2nd time I hover the link that the tooltip appears again.

I have seen the post [jquery tools tooltip doesn't appear in first try after hide()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218633/jquery-tools-tooltip-doesnt-appear-in-first-try-after-hide) but could see how the fix for this issue could help me with mine.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   $(document).click(function () {
       $(".tooltip").fadeOut();           
   });

   $(".tooltip").click(function (e) {
       e.stopPropagation();
   });

   $(document).keypress(function (e) {
       if (e.keyCode == 27) {
           $(".tooltip").fadeOut();
       }
   });

   $(".uploadImage").tooltip({ effect: 'fade',
       events: {
           input: 'click, focus',
           checkbox: 'mouseover click, mouseout',
           date: 'click, blur',
           tooltip: "mouseenter"
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: I vividly remember having a similar problem in past... what helped me was removing the tooltip completely after hiding it - perhaps something you can look into as well?

Comment: unfortunately I have looked into the .destroy() but I need the tooltip to display anytime the link is hovered over as there is a form inside that needs to be displayed to allow an upload.

Comment: unless it's possible to regenerate the form in the tooltip on hover? it's probably a long shot and there would be some much cleaner solution floating somewhere, so I wish you best of luck in finding it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using .on() function.

```
$(document).on('click', 'body', function(){
  $('.tooltop').fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Hi Jan, thanks for the comment but this didn't work. I don't think its anything to do with the `fadeOut()` functions as they work as intended. I thinks its that `effect:'fade'` on the `$(".uploadImage").tooltip()` that isn't registering until a second hover. could the `fadeOut()` be removing a property that jQuery tools need to display a tooltip?

Comment: I was also wondering if i could rebind the `.tooltip()` to `$(".uploadImage")` after a `fadeOut()`?